# How to return the number of trials (n) in a binomial distribution for a given probability using library function scipy.stats.binom.pmf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics, binomial-theorem

Is it possible to get `scipy.stats.binom.pmf(x, n, p)` to return the number of trials (*n*) with the probabaility, number of successes (*x*), and probability of successes (*p*) known?

***Example Problem:***

*How many throws does Alex need to do in order to be 90% sure of hitting the target at least 10 times?*

where:

- Probability = 0.90
- p = 0.50
- x = 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this. What you want to compute is what `scipy.stats` calls the survival function (`sf`) which is `1-cdf`. Since you are interested in greater than or equal to 10 success--that is the sum of the probabilities of 10 or more successes, that is precisely `1-cdf`. The `sf` function can take a numpy array for the arguments, so we pass in an array for `n` (varying the number of trials). We then look for the number of trials that gave us a value greater than the defined `confidence`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Defining model parameters
p = 0.5
k = 10
confidence = 0.9
n = np.arange(k, 5*k)

# Generating survival function distribution and computing the number of required trials
binomSurvivalDist = scipy.stats.binom.sf(k, n, p)
nrequired = n[binomSurvivalDist >= confidence][0]

# Plotting the results to Verify that this works
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 10))
x = np.arange(0, nrequired+1, 1)
ax.plot(x, scipy.stats.binom.sf(x, nrequired, p), lw=2)
ax.set_xlabel("Number of Successes", fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel("Probability of Getting At Least this Many Success", fontsize=16)
ax.set_title("Distribution for %i Trials" % nrequired, fontsize=18)

print(nrequired)
plt.show()
```

The plot is not necessary for the computation, but allows us to verify that the procedure does give us the correct answer.